# In Xubuntu 14.04.1, Customizing Date & Time Display

Tags: xubuntu, time, date

In Xubuntu 14.04.1, how do you enlarge the font size of the date and time in the top right panel area?

Answer (score 5):

The digital clock display is very configurable. See these links for more information on how to customize the clock the way you want:

http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/clock

https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html

I don't recall the original clock format, but here are a few simple examples below: (copy paste one line at a time into the clock's custom format to try them out)

Right click on the clock and click properties, Then choose the Digital layout, Then choose "Custom Format" for "Clock Options".

First, You can try the bold and big attributes to make text easier to read:

```
%l:%M %P (default style)
<b>%l:%M %P</b>
<big>%l:%M %P</big>
<big><b>%l:%M %P</b></big>
```

Second, you can try the span font-size and font-weight attributes to get more specific sizes:

```
%l:%M %P (default Style)
<span weight='bold'>%l:%M %P</span>
<span font='16'>%l:%M %P</span>
<span font='16' weight='bold'>%l:%M %P</span>
```

And lastly, here are some multi-line examples for tall panels:

```
<big><b>%l:%M</b></big> %P%n%A
<span font='14' weight='bold'>%l:%M</span><span weight='bold'> %P%n%A</span>
```